# Assign a value to the variable in Splunk and use that value in the search

Tags: splunk

I have a use-case where I want to set the value to a variable based on the condition and use that variable in the search command.

Example:-
I want to check the condition

```
    if account_no=818

    then var1="vpc-06b"

    else var1="*"
```

I tried

```
...|eval val1=case(acc_no==818,"vpc-06b",acc_no!=818,"*")|search vpc_id=val1
```

but I am not getting any event. If I am trying

```
...|search vpc_id=vpc-06b
```

then, as a result, I am getting the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
index=... (acc-number=818 AND (vpc_id="vpc-078" OR vpc_id="vpc-02c" )) OR (acc-number!=818 AND vpc_id="*")
```

(You don't actually need the `AND`s, I'm just including them to make it clearer. The following is also acceptable.

```
index=... (acc-number=818 (vpc_id="vpc-078" OR vpc_id="vpc-02c" )) OR (acc-number!=818 vpc_id="*")
```

Comment: Any idea of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705525/how-to-use-boto3-in-splunk-enterprise

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the field `vpc_id` extracted? If you do the search `... | stats count by vpc_id`, do you get results split by `vpc_id`?

The reason I ask this is that your second search shouldn't work, `...|search vpc_id=vpc-06b`. What I expect would work, if you had the field extracted, would be `...|search vpc_id="vpc-06b"`. If the second case works, then your logic with the `case` statement is correct.

I'm going to assume that the field has not been extracted properly. In that case, I suggest you try the following. I use the `rex` command to force the field to be extracted, then use that in the comparison.

```
... | rex field=_raw "vpc_id=(?<vpc_id>\S+)" | eval val1=case(acc_no==818,"vpc-06b",acc_no!=818,"*") | where vpc_id=val1
```

Comment: Hi Simon,

vpc_id field is properly extracted, yes I am getting the result split by vpc_id.

Actually the problem which I found here is I have multiple values of vpc_id which i need to set to the variable using OR like for example

...| eval val1=case(acc_no==818,"vpc-06b OR vpc_067b",acc_no!=818,"*") | where vpc_id=val1.

As we give in the normal search lets say val1="vpc-06b" OR "vpc_067b"

Comment: if I am trying this query 
|search vpc_id="vpc-078" OR "vpc-02c" then it works as expected. Same way I want the result to get populated using the condition specified.

Comment: It would be great if You can help me out. Thanks in advance Simon.

Comment: I think you're better off using a subsearch. I will post that as a separate answer.

Comment: Actually, could you post your entire use-case and some sample events? I'm not sure how the account number is related to the other events you are looking for.

Comment: The usecase is I have to search for only those events which have field vpc_id="vpc-078" OR "vpc-02c" when acc-number =818. For rest of the accounts i have to search  for all the events regardless of the vpc-id.

Comment: So you are looking for 2 fields in the same event? In that case you want `(acc-number=818 AND (vpc_id="vpc-078" OR vpc_id="vpc-02c" )) OR (acc-number!=818 AND vpc_id="*")`