# How to use boto3 in splunk Enterprise

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, splunk

I am trying to create a custom app for my usecases in splunk. One of my usecase is to get some data from AWS for which I already have a working code written in python and I am using boto3 SDK. The same code I was trying in Splunk and it didn't work because Splunk doesn't have information of boto3. Any suggestions please.

The sample code is here.

```
import boto3
import json

def ec2_client():
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    """ :type : pyboto3.ec2 """
    return client;

def perform_ec2_operation():
    ec2_interested_details = ec2_client().describe_instances()
    #print(ec2_interested_details)
    return ec2_interested_details;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = perform_ec2_operation()
    data = data['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['NetworkInterfaces'][0]['Association']
    data = json.dumps(data);
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your script is failing is because Splunk uses its own deployment of Python. You will need to install boto3 into that Python's library, which can be challenging. Refer to the following:

- https://answers.splunk.com/answers/220196/import-non-native-python-libraries-into-splunk.html
- https://answers.splunk.com/answers/8/can-i-add-python-modules-to-the-splunk-environment.html
- https://answers.splunk.com/answers/112609/my-own-python-script-cannot-import-splunk-python-library-modules.html

Are you creating a custom input to retrieve your data from AWS? If so, I suggest you instead look at the Splunk created add-on for AWS, https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1876/ This will have all the necessary libraries configured for you already.

Comment: Actually i have some usecases which add-on for AWS is not fullfilling. We already are using that add-on. For example one of the usecase is to get the data of resources like, s3, EC2, EFS and check whether they are Compliant or not. and other is os patching etc. so for that reason i am creating a new addon. How complex it would be any suggestions from your side?

Comment: One more thing , I have splunk running on cloud as well where actually i have to add this add-on at the end after building this in my local. Your suggestions would be of great use.

Comment: Are you in Splunk Cloud, or your own cloud?

Comment: our splunk is running in aws cloud.

Comment: I have resolved boto3 issue by adding the libraray into spluck's python directory. When this add-on will be used in other machine is it required to add boto3 library in that machine as well, or it should go with the add-on package.