# Where are variables in splunk defined

Tags: splunk

I have an alert setup in splunk which uses below search string.

```
index="someapp" sourcetype = "some:app" "some_scheduler" "ERROR" 
| regex source = "(lambda:prod)"
```

I am not able to find where `(lambda:prod)` is defined. This search query works globally so I am assuming it's not something defined at app level or something.

Comment: Try to refer to this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622256/assign-a-value-to-the-variable-in-splunk-and-use-that-value-in-the-search

Answer (score 1):

`(lambda:prod)` is not **defined** anywhere.  It is a literal string interpreted as a regular expression.  That regex is used to match against the results returned by the commands prior to `regex`.  Any event with a `source` field which matches the regex will be included in the results and all other events will be filtered.